# Java -server option vs Server JRE

Tags: java

Based on this: [Use of java -server option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608639/use-of-java-server-option)

I am using a 64-bit JDK (yes JDK) to run my application, therefore I am already implicitly running the Server Hotspot VM.

My question is, is that the equivalent of running the Server JRE that is available on the Oracle website?