# Does the server option still exist?

Tags: openjdk-11

I am looking for the server option of the jvm.

I try java -h but this option is not displayed.

It does not exist with the open jdk 11 ?

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: I'm unable to find sources right now, but AFAIK the `-server` option has been deprecated for quite some time or had no effect anyway (maybe there was a difference between 32 and 64 bit JVMs?)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608794/112968 which explains that this is already implied for 64 bit JVMs (so I would assume this is now always the default)

Comment: I should miss a point, looking at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html a server option is described : java -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseLargePages -Xmn10g -Xms26g -Xmx26g